# hibernate: retrieving some fields on a single table but using non-selected fields in the where clause

Tags: hibernate

I'm looking to move our staff directory into a java using spring/maven/hibernate.

I'm a bit confused with the hibernate bit specifically on declaring my class and mapping.

**situation:**

```
I got 10 fields in my table labelled column01 to column10.
I only want to retrieve columns 02, 07 to 10.
But my where clause would be using columns 01, 05 and 06.
```

1. When I create my class and hibernate mapping XML, is it good practice to declare all fields even though I won't be using all the columns? Should I even declare fields I will only be using only of the where clause?
2. Also is it possible to use database specific functions and keywords (in my case, it would be Oracle) in my createSQL function?

I've looked at examples and the jboss.org page on HQL but can't really find what I'm after. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to use HQL (Hibernate Query Language), you must define all fields which are used in select clause, where clause, sorting, grouping in your mappings. So best answer is yes to your first question.
2. Yes, you can, Hibernate knows much about databases using Dialects, besides it supports Native Queries, and even mapping DML queries to stored procedure calls. Just read the [documentations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html).